# Efficient Perl Time Zone Conversion

Tags: perl, datetime, optimization

I'm using DateTime::TimeZone to process users' time zones and convert times of posts to the proper local time. It seems to work well, but it seems to be relatively costly timewise (according to NYTProf, 39% of my program's runtime -- 343ms -- is going to checking the validity of 1 time zone given as input (214ms) and then processing a series of 10 or 15 dates again it (129ms). This isn't a huge amount of time, but if a page has several AJAX requests against the same code that does this, it becomes more noticeable.

Here's the code I'm dealing with: I test (once on startup) whether the user has a valid time zone and otherwise default to a default time zone:

```
use DateTime;
use DateTime::TimeZone;
$author{'timeZone'} = $config{'timeZone'} unless (DateTime::TimeZone->is_valid_name($author{'timeZone'}));
```

Here is what is run against each entry that has a timestamp:

```
my $dt = DateTime->from_epoch( epoch => $inputtime, time_zone => $author{'timeZone'});
```

Is there a way to optimize this process that would speed up the process?

Comment: I haven't used perl where speed matters so I don't know how good it is at optimizing things. You could try to remove all the hash lookups that you probably only need to do once at program startup (or rarely, like once a day), like `my $timeZone = $config{'timeZone'};` and then use `$timeZone` instead of `$config{'timeZone'}` in the rest of the program.

Comment: Is this CGI or a constantly running service? Does startup time matter? // Note that under NYTProf everything takes significantly longer because it's expensive to collect all of the data. Run your code through a benchmarking tool without NYTProf to get a general idea of whether it's too slow. The first rule of profiling is that you probably don't need it.

Comment: @TedLyngmo That's an interesting idea -- I'm not noticing much lag there, but it is worth investigating.

Comment: @simbabque It is CGI. I started profiling with NYTProf when I noticed that my pages had reach a second to a second and a half to load using Google Lighthouse or ApacheBench. I've been attacking the "really big" chunks of what NYTProf highlighted for lack of a better idea on the problem and cut the load time by 50% so far. NYTProf seems to be relatively closely mirroring ApacheBench +/- 100ms.

Comment: You should pass a ::TimeZone object instead of the passing the string repeatedly.

Comment: For the conversion, you can set env var TZ and use `locatime`. (You're supposed to call `tzset` from POSIX, but you might not need to.) Not sure how to validate.

Comment: `DateTime::TimeZone->new(name => 'foo/bar')` will die because it can't load that TZ. This is what `is_valid_name` does internally. So creating inside an `eval` outside the loop should be enough.

Comment: Why not store everything in UTC and let the client convert it for its local time?

Comment: @ikegami I'll give that a try. Thanks.

Comment: @briandfoy Everything is stored in UTC. I hadn't thought about leaving conversion up to JavaScript or some such... that's an intriguing idea...